# CSS Distort In Horizontal Alignment

Tags: html, css, oracle, datepicker, oracle-apex

I'm producing an application using Oracle APEX, unfortunately APEX still doesn't support RTL so I'm doing it my own custom way. I've got a tabular form with a date column shown with a datepicker.

I want the datepicker trigger button to be on the right hand side of the input field.

When using `float: left` I have a distortion issue. It's a bit difficult recreating the same situation so I'll go with a screenshot.

This is what it initially looks like :

[image: Initial Screenshot]

And this is what it looks like after adding the float style:

[image: Distorted Screenshot]

This is what the html code looks like :

```
<td headers="CAL_DATE">
<span style="direction: ltr">
    <label for="f03_0001" id="f03_0001_LABEL" class="u-VisuallyHidden">Cal Date</label>
    <span style="white-space: nowrap;">
        <button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-trigger">
            <span class="a-Icon icon-calendar"></span>
            <span class="u-VisuallyHidden">پنجره تقويم: Cal Date
                <span></span>
            </span>
        </button>
        <input type="text" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--datepicker  hasDatepicker" id="f03_0001" name="f03" maxlength="2000" size="12" value="2012/07/11" autocomplete="off">
        </span>
    </span>
</td>
```

This is the css for the **ui-datepicker-trigger** class :

```
.ui-datepicker-trigger {
margin: 0 0 0 2px;
vertical-align: top;
float: left;}
```

I would very much appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: ".ui-datepicker-trigger" add display:inline-block - Remove float

Comment: thanks, seems like using the float or display style worked, just had to add it to the span and not the datepicker trigger itself

Comment: RTL = "right to left".  I had to Google that!

Comment: @TonyAndrews lol, seriously? RTL is a totally different world

Comment: @TonyAndrews and plus, one of Apex 5.1's features is native RTL support

Comment: @FarzadSoltani yes I knew about right-to-left support in 5.1, I just wasn't familiar with the abbreviation "RTL" - I thought maybe it was some kind of CSS pre-processing tool like SASS that I had't heard of yet!

Comment: @TonyAndrews lol, my bad then, should've made it more clear